# Recursive Backtracking Does Not Back Track

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I have been struggling to solve the following question using Recessive Backtracking in C++. The problem is that it does not backtrack. I tracked my algorithm manually on a paper and it works on the paper. So problem is I don't know how to implement that in C++. Any help will be appreciated.

**Question:**

Given a 2-dimensional grid representing elevations of a map, determine the lowest and highest points and whether there is a path between them that never goes down.

Input

Your program will receive the following command line arguments:

```
<fname> File name for the 2-dimensional map
<M>     Number of rows
<N>     Number of columns
```

Output

Your program should write 5 values to the standard output: Lr Lc Hr Hc YESNO where Lr Lc are the row and column of the lowest point in the grid, Hr Hc are the row and column of the highest point in the grid, and YESNO is the word: yes if there is a path from the lowest point to the highest point that never goes down and no if there is no such path. Specifically, the path starts at the lowest point and can only go from a point to one of its 4-neighbors (left, right, up, or down) that does NOT have a lower elevation than the point. Input will be such that there is a unique solution.

**The problem is with the "path" function.**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>
// using namespace std;

void ReadFile(std::string fname, std::vector<std::vector<int>> *const vec_2d);

// What about min? row and col are initially the min, but then get updated
void min_max(std::vector<std::vector<int>> *const vec_2d,
             std::vector<int> &vec_1d,
             int num_rows,
             int num_cols,
             int &row,
             int &col,
             int &idx_i_max,
             int &idx_j_max,
             int &cur_val); //grid is vec_2d??????
             
int path(std::vector<int> vec_1d,
         int row,
         int col,
         int num_rows,
         int num_cols,
         int idx_i_max,
         int idx_j_max,
         int &cur_val); // bool *visited is a pointer type bool which could be a 2-d array??
         
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec_2d;
    
    std::vector<int> vec_1d;
    // declare variables
    int num_rows, num_cols, row, col, idx_i_max, idx_j_max, cur_val;
    
    std::string fname;
    
    // get .txt file containing the grid
    fname = argv[1]; //string of file name
            
    num_rows = atoi(argv[2]); // convert argument strings to integers
    num_cols = atoi(argv[3]);
    
    // bool visited[100][100];
    //2D vector initialized with user defined size
    // std::vector<std::vector<int>> visited(num_rows, std::vector<int>(num_cols));
    
    ReadFile(fname, &vec_2d); //reading the .txt file and assigning to vec_2d
             
    min_max(&vec_2d,
            vec_1d,
            num_rows,
            num_cols,
            row,
            col,
            idx_i_max,
            idx_j_max,
            cur_val);
    
    path(vec_1d, row, col, num_rows, num_cols, idx_i_max, idx_j_max, cur_val);
}

void ReadFile(std::string fname, std::vector<std::vector<int>> *const vec_2d)
{ //it is a pointer to a vector,therefore, after end of func, it will still exist // Create the input filestream - opens the file & prepares it for reading

    std::ifstream file(fname);
    
    std::string str; // Temporary string to hold a single line of the file
    
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    { // Reads all lines in the file, 1 at at time
    
        std::vector<int> new_row; // Creates a temporary vector to represent one row
        
        std::istringstream ss(str); // Converts our string into a stringstream
        
        int token; // Temp int to store a converted value from a line
        
        while (ss >> token)
        { // Reads all values from the stringstream (current row), converts to int
        
            new_row.push_back(token); // Adds the converted value to the row
        }
        
        vec_2d->push_back(new_row); // Pushes our constructed vector of ints to the 2D vector
    }
}

void min_max(std::vector<std::vector<int>> *const vec_2d,
             std::vector<int> &vec_1d,
             int num_rows,
             int num_cols,
             int &row,
             int &col,
             int &idx_i_max,
             int &idx_j_max,
             int &cur_val)
{ //I dont need any argument for this func

    //Converting 2-d vec to 1-d to find loc of min and max
    
    for (int i = 0; i < (*vec_2d).size(); i++)
    {
        
        for (int j = 0; j < (*vec_2d)[i].size(); j++)
        {
            
            vec_1d.push_back((*vec_2d)[i][j]);
        }
    }
    // finding the max and min values in the grid vector and save thier index (max_idx and min_idx)
    int max_idx, min_idx; // Initialize two int for index of max and min values
            
    // 
    int maxElementIndex = std::max_element(vec_1d.begin(), vec_1d.end())
            - vec_1d.begin(); //max elem index //I need to convert 2d to 1d vector to use this func
            
    int minElementIndex = std::min_element(vec_1d.begin(), vec_1d.end())
            - vec_1d.begin(); //min elem index
            
            //convert 1-d  vec idx to 2-d vec idx
    idx_i_max = (maxElementIndex / num_cols) + 1; //actual idx + 1
            
    idx_j_max = (maxElementIndex % num_cols) + 1; //actual idx + 1
            
    int idx_i_min = (minElementIndex / num_cols) + 1; //actual idx + 1
            
    int idx_j_min = (minElementIndex % num_cols) + 1; //actual idx + 1
            
    //      The initial current value is the minimum
    cur_val = *std::min_element(vec_1d.begin(), vec_1d.end());
    
    //loc of min will be our start point as below
    row = idx_i_min; //actual idx + 1
            
    col = idx_j_min; //actual idx + 1
            
    // print i and j idx of min and max respectively (with a space after each)
    
    std::cout << idx_i_min << " ";
    
    std::cout << idx_j_min << " ";
    
    std::cout << idx_i_max << " ";
    
    std::cout << idx_j_max << " "; //This prints are working fine
            
    // A recursive backtracking function to go over all cells. base case is when all directions are impossible, then retuen 0
}
//row and col will be changed in every recursion. should they be const???
int path(std::vector<int> vec_1d,
         int row,
         int col,
         int num_rows,
         int num_cols,
         int idx_i_max,
         int idx_j_max,
         int &cur_val)
{
    
    //  std::cout<<"test"<<std::endl;
    
    std::cout << std::endl << row << " " << col << std::endl; // it atops at the second cell
            
    // std::cout<<cur_val<<std::endl;//it prints the start point twice
    
    // if the evaluating neighbor cell is equal to max value
    if (row == idx_i_max && col == idx_j_max)
    { //base case
    
        std::cout << "yes";
        
        return 1;
    }
    
    else
    {
        
        cur_val = vec_1d[((row - 1) * num_cols) + (col - 1)]; //updating the current value  
                
        //Checking the north neighbor (COND1)
        if (row - 1 > 0
                && vec_1d[((row - 1 - 1) * num_cols) + (col - 1)] >= cur_val)
        { //if the north cell is -1
        
            vec_1d[((row - 1) * num_cols) + (col - 1)] = -1; // making the current cell as visited
                    
            path(vec_1d,
                 row - 1,
                 col,
                 num_rows,
                 num_cols,
                 idx_i_max,
                 idx_j_max,
                 cur_val);
            
            return 1;
        }
        
        //Checking the south neighbor(COND2)
        if (row + 1 <= num_rows
                && vec_1d[((row + 1 - 1) * num_cols) + (col - 1)] >= cur_val)
        {
            
            vec_1d[((row - 1) * num_cols) + (col - 1)] = -1;
            
            path(vec_1d,
                 row + 1,
                 col,
                 num_rows,
                 num_cols,
                 idx_i_max,
                 idx_j_max,
                 cur_val);
            return 1;
        }
        
        //Checking the west neighbor(COND3)
        if (col - 1 > 0
                && vec_1d[((row - 1) * num_cols) + (col - 1 - 1)] >= cur_val)
        {
            
            vec_1d[((row - 1) * num_cols) + (col - 1)] = -1;
            
            path(vec_1d,
                 row,
                 col - 1,
                 num_rows,
                 num_cols,
                 idx_i_max,
                 idx_j_max,
                 cur_val);
            
            return 1;
        }
        
        //Checking the east neighbor(COND4)
        if (col + 1 <= num_cols
                && vec_1d[((row - 1) * num_cols) + (col + 1 - 1)] >= cur_val)
        {
            
            vec_1d[((row - 1) * num_cols) + (col - 1)] = -1;
            
            path(vec_1d,
                 row,
                 col + 1,
                 num_rows,
                 num_cols,
                 idx_i_max,
                 idx_j_max,
                 cur_val);
            
            return 1;
        }
        
        // return 0;
        
    }
    // FORGET ABOUT PRINTING YES/NO. FOCUS ON THE PRINT OF CURRENT CELL
    // if(path){
    
    //         std::cout<<"yes";
    // }
    // else{
    
    //         std::cout<<"no";
    // }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I get [a bunch of compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/do7rWEe8z) from this code. You should address them before you start debugging. The compiler might be telling you what's wrong.

Comment: @user4581301Suprisingly I dont have any compiling error!

Comment: No errors. The one important warning is that `path` can be exited without returning a value and this is not deemed to be a hard error because it's possible to write functions that never return except under a particular circumstance that is covered by a return. This warning could be the compiler making a mistake, but you need to confirm that commenting out the `return 0;` at the end of the function is not a mistake or contributing to a mistake.

Comment: You can verify if you are invoking undefined behavior by putting a `std::cout << "I'm in trouble" << std::endl;` before the last `}` in the `path` function.  If you see that output, you know you're in trouble.  That output means that you are returning from a function that requires you to return an `int`, but you failed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

```
^ g++ Foo.cpp -Wall --std=c++17 -o Foo
Foo.cpp: In function ‘void min_max(std::vector<std::vector<int> >*, std::vector<int>&, int, int, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&)’:
Foo.cpp:107:23: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for (int i = 0; i < (*vec_2d).size(); i++)
                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Foo.cpp:110:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         for (int j = 0; j < (*vec_2d)[i].size(); j++)
                         ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Foo.cpp:117:9: warning: unused variable ‘max_idx’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int max_idx, min_idx; // Initialize two int for index of max and min values
         ^~~~~~~
Foo.cpp:117:18: warning: unused variable ‘min_idx’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int max_idx, min_idx; // Initialize two int for index of max and min values
                  ^~~~~~~
Foo.cpp: In function ‘int path(std::vector<int>, int, int, int, int, int, int, int&)’:
Foo.cpp:273:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Adding the `-Wall` flag on your compile will tell the compiler to help you find silly mistakes. I'd fix these warnings and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but unfortunately it does help in understanding how I can correct the code to fix back tracking @Joseph Larson

Comment: Did you try fixing the warnings? The last one is potentially significant.